# Liferay 7 : Customize a form

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I want to create and customize a form in **Liferay-7**, and I really don't know how to make it , because i can't modify the liferay standard form.
Any idea about how can I start?

What I want to create : [image]

***Thank you***  .

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty much a basic form and you just need a different layout set. Following this documentation [here](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-advanced-forms). This should help you in building the form you need.

Comment: Thank you for the link , but the problem is the layout , I just wanted to put one long paragraph on the right & all the fields on the left.
and that paragraph can cover ann the fields height as the image show

Comment: IMO, its still possible. Look at the form layout section in the link I shared.

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt help, the final code should be like :
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"> <p>Paragraph</p> </div><div class="col-md-6">here where i can put the form inputs</div> </div>